# How to merge objects attributes from reduce to rereduce function in CouchDB

Tags: javascript, view, couchdb, reduce

This is my JSON schema:

```
{"emp_no": ..,
"salary": ..,
"from_date": ..,
"to_date": ..,
"type" : "salaries"}

{"emp_no": ..,
"title": ..,
"from_date": ..,
"to_date" : ..,
"type" : "titles"}
```

What i wanted to do, is to find the average salary for each active title. Active titles are document with "from_date" attribute set to "9999-01-01"

Here is my Map Function

```
function(doc) {
if (doc.type == 'salaries') {
        var dateSalaries = null;
        dateSalaries = doc.to_date.split("-");
        if(dateSalaries[0].localeCompare("9999") == 0){
            emit(doc.emp_no, ["salary", doc.salary] );
        }
    } else if (doc.type == 'titles') {
        var dateTitles = null;
        dateTitles = doc.to_date.split("-");
        if(dateTitles[0].localeCompare("9999") == 0){
            emit(doc.emp_no, ["title", doc.title]);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the resulting key value pairs emited:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzh8z.png

Now, i want to reduce it into single key-value pair, with the value outputted is set into javascript object like this

```
{
    "engineer" : 64342,
    "senior engineer" : 123111,
    "staff" : ...,
    "senior staf" : ...,
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Here's how i planned to do it: First, in reduce step, i'm gonna return object that merge properties from the same emp_no. Then, in reduce step, i'm gonna create a new object  that has properties name based on reduced value before.

It's hard to explain, so here is my reduce function:

```
function(keys, values, rereduce) {
    var i, l, attr, sal, rv = {};
    if (rereduce) {
        for (i = 0, l = values.length; i<l ; ++i) {
            if (values[i].hasOwnProperty('salary')) {
                attr = values[i].title;
                sal = values[i].salary;
                if (rv[attr] instanceof Array) {
                    rv[attr].push(sal);
                } else{
                    rv[attr] = [];
                    rv[attr].push(sal);
                }
            }           
        }

        for (var x in rv) {
            if (rv.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
                var totalSalary = 0;
                for (i = 0, l = values.length; i<l ; i++) {
                    totalSalary += rv[x][i];
                }
                rv[x] = totalSalary / rv[x].length;
            }
        }

    } else {
        for (i = 0, l = values.length; i<l ; i++) {
            switch (values[i][0]) {
                case "title" : rv["title"] = values[i][1]; break;
                case "salary": rv["salary"] = values[i][1]; break;
            }
        }
    }
    return rv;
}
```

The resulting value here is reduced value, which is what i expected: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqRfM.png

But, when i set the grouping value to 'none' in futon, it's not what i wanted:

```
{Senior Engineer: null, Assistant Engineer: null, Technique Leader: null}
```

Could someone help me to solves this?

Comment: I've changed the rereduce step, but still troubled to find the average salaries. Here's the follow-up question: (http://stackoverflow.com/q/11231108/1448852)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pushing CouchDB pretty close to its limits here — using a reduce function to perform a join and everything.

Your problem comes from the fact that CouchDB may apply zero, one or more rereduce steps, but your code assumes that exactly one rereduce step will be performed. I suspect the `null` results you get come from the fact that the final rereduce step is applied to some results that come from a reduce step and some results that come from a rereduce step.

Here's a small diagram. M is a map step, R is a reduce step, RR is a rereduce step.

```
[X] [X] [X] [X] [X] [X] [X] [X] [X] [X] 
 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 
(M) (M) (M) (M) (M) (M) (M) (M) (M) (M)
 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 
(==R==) (==R==) (==R==) (==R==) (==R==)
   |       |       |       |       | 
  (== R R ==)     (== R R ==)      | 
       |               |           | 
      (====== R R ======)          | 
               |                   | 
              (======== R R ========)
                         |
                         v
                        [X]
```

With CouchDB reduce views, it is essential that the data output by your reduce step has the same format as the data output by your rereduce steps. In particular, this means that instead of storing averages, you need to store (sum,count) pairs.

Comment: Wow, i thought that since rereduce will merge into one kvp, i can assume that it will run serially in array. I never thought that the Rereduced output must be the same as reduce..
But, i can't seem to find any other way to address this problem. How can i find each title average salaries?

Comment: Have reduce and rereduce steps output dictionaries of the form `{"Title":[sum,count],"Title":[sum,count]}`. Reduce outputs only one title, and rereduce can easily combine these dictionaries together. The averages won't be computed for you, but you can compute them easily on the client side (divide sum by count).

Answer (score 0):

It would make your life a lot easier if you could put the title and salary in the same employee document together.

```
{
"name" : "Joe",
"title" : "Plumber",
"salary" : 60000
}
```

then you could easily `emit(doc.title, doc.salary)` with the built-in `_stats` reduce function and get a view of salary stats for each title.

Comment: I'm trying to modelling this employee schema with different approach. This one is more normalized structure. The other one is self-contained approach. So far, self-contained is easier..